# Describe in English the pattern in the following regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions

Describe (in English phrases) the languages associated with the following regular expression. it says to be as simple as possible

```
#1 (x (yyy + x)*)*
#2 (c (cc)*d(dd)*)*
```

for number 1 I got all words in which when y is in the word it can only appear in blocks that are divisible by 3(0,3,6,9, etc.)

the second question I can not see any type of pattern.

I would like to know if the first one is correct, and if what pattern is on the second one?

Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what to do about number 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is very close, but not quite right. Your phrasing technically allows strings that start with $yyy$, but the language contains no such string. There are lots of ways to fix what you have to incorporate this. For instance, you might try "all strings in which $y$s appear only in blocks of length divisible by $3$ preceded by at least one $x$." You'll want to check that to make sure it's right, of course.

The second one isn't too bad. Notice that a description of the regular expression inside the outermost parentheses might be "an odd number of $c$s followed by an odd number of $d$s." By applying the Kleene star, we allow this to be repeated an arbitrary number of times. Something like "All strings which, if non-empty, start with a $c$, end with a $d$ and alternate blocks of $c$s and $d$s of odd lengths," should be close.

Some general pointers:

1. Work from the inside out. Describe the subexpressions first, and use those descriptions to describe expressions.
2. If you're not seeing a pattern, it never hurts to write out some representative strings.
3. Pay special attention to boundary cases, especially around the empty string. Natural language tends to be a little unclear when it comes to things existing, satisfying properties vacuously, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick87. This is exactly what I needed, and thanks for those general pointers as well. It is really helping me understand this a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

2) An empty string, or a series of arbitrary length made of subseries consisting of cs necessarily followed by ds, where within each subseries the number of cs and ds can never be divisible by 2.

And actually for the other one I think:

1) An empty string, or a series of arbitrary length made of subseries beginning with an x followed by any number of xs and ys, where within each subseries any occurrence of y must be in a contiguous group of ys whose length must be divisible by 3.

When I turned your rendition of 1) into a regular expression I got this:

(. + yyy)* where . is ANYTHING.